# How to acces JSTL value in servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

My Jsp Page is ProductList.jsp

```
        <table id="table">
        <tr id="firstrow"><th>Product Name</th><th>Quantity</th>          <th>Price/unit</th><th>Vendor's Name</th><th>actions</th></tr>
        <tr>
        <c:forEach var="current" items="${sessionScope.productname}" >
        <td><c:out value="${current.productName}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${current.quantity}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${current.price}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${current.vname}"/></td>
        <td><form action="./editdetails" method="post"><input type="submit"    value="Edit">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete"></td>
        </form>
        </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

from which I want access the productName ,quantity,price and vname . I am trying to get those table data values in my EditProductDetails.java servlet page.Because I need to fetch this value in anothe jsp page for further Edit.
Here is my code.

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse    response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    //doGet(request, response);
    String productName=request.getParameter("productName");
    int qnty =Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("quantity"));
    Float prce=Float.parseFloat(request.getParameter("price"));
    String vendorName=request.getParameter("vname");
    String action=request.getParameter("./editdetails");
    if(ShowProducDetailsForEdit.showProductDetails(productName,qnty,prce,vendorName)){
        request.getSession().setAttribute("productname", productName);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("quantity", qnty);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("price",prce);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("vendorName", vendorName);
        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("Edit.jsp");    
        rd.include(request,response);
    }

}
```

But I am getting java.lang.NumberFormatException: and it is showing that

```
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
com.pms.servlets.EditProductDetails.doPost(EditProductDetails.java:44)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

:
In beloow lines request.getParameter("") couldn't recognize those values.

```
    String productName=request.getParameter("productName");
    int qnty =Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("quantity"));
    Float prce=Float.parseFloat(request.getParameter("price"));
```

My question is -what I should write in request.getParameter("")? So that my error doesn't occur again. I am a beginner of Jsp Servlet . So I need help to solve this problem.

My web.xml file is

```
 <servlet>
<servlet-name>mygenser4</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.pms.servlets.EditProductDetails</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>mygenser4</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/editdetails</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: How is the servlet getting called? and what are you sending in your request?

Comment: Ditto. I'd like to add that it's unlikely that you have a POST parameter named `./editdetails`, but I guess you could, it' just *very* unusual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `<form>` is just (notice the misplaced `</td>`):

```
<td><form action="./editdetails" method="post">
  <input type="submit"    value="Edit">
  <input type="submit" value="Delete"></td>
</form>
```

there are not parameters being posted, which means that `request.getParameter()` will return null for any and all names.

To actually post values you'd need some `<input>`, `<button>`, `<select>`, or `<textarea>` elements with `name=` attributes *inside* the `<form>`.

In your case, that would be `<input type="hidden">` elements (misplaced `</td>` moved):

```
<td><form action="editdetails" method="post">
  <input type="submit" name="action" value="Edit">
  <input type="submit" name="action" value="Delete">
  <input type="hidden" name="productName" value="<c:out value="${current.productName}"/>">
  <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="<c:out value="${current.quantity}"/>">
  <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<c:out value="${current.price}"/>">
  <input type="hidden" name="vname" value="<c:out value="${current.vname}"/>">
</form></td>
```

Also note that the submit buttons have been named so the `doPost` can check the `"action"` parameter to see whether to edit or delete.

Comment: Sorry for late reply but it's really helping